# Element before:width cannot be greater than defined in the tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a problem where the size of the before:width element is not getting bigger than the defined without the before

I need to make the element a perfect circle.

Image of how it looks, the width is not greater than 250px

[image]

**My Code**:

```
<div class="absolute w-[250px] h-[50px] text-white">
      <a class="absolute flex items-center w-full h-full rounded-full before:rounded-full before:w-[300px] before:h-[300px] before:bg-white">    
        <span class="">test</span>
      </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you probably have overflow hidden on your circle, add `overflow-visible` to your circle should fix the problem

Comment: I already tested it and it doesn't work

Comment: well please post more of your css and html, for anyone to be able to help you we need more information